# How to do subqueries to avoid the 61 join table limit problem using springboot, hibernate and mysql

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

To summarize my problem, I have an entity A and B as follows:

[image]

When I try to find all entities A, following error occurs: creates a join with more than 61 tables. That's because mysql does not allow the use of more than 61 joins per query.
I will want to know if there is an alternative to make my entity do the join with table B once for all its fileds (to optimize the number of join) or if there a configuration to add or modify so that hibernate splits the sql requests into sub-requests?

I'm using, springboot , mysql, hibernate and JpaRepository (for persistance).

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Does the `JOIN` limit apply to derived tables?  Subqueries?  `UNIONs`?

Comment: Perhaps your schema is "over-normalized".

Comment: In your place I will think to change the database schema by making the relation between A and B one to many, then in the Class A i will create a Set<B> and mapped it to B table.

Comment: I cannot add all 100 fields to the same list, otherwise the Swagger documentation output which is automatically generated will be wrong.
I have to keep the same number of fields. and I can't change the database structure either.

I have to find another alternative.

Comment: saw your question on DZdev, did you find a solution?